# How to dynamically change pagination urls in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I have two data grids. The first auto-loads a list of items (json data store). OnCellClick the first grid fires a dynamically parametrized url and loads data into the second grid. It works fine, but the pagination of the second grid does not focus the new context. 
What shall I do to make the pagination work with the new url?

Answer (score 1):

hm your pagination and second grid (which is the one to be dynamical) should share the same store, now on cell click you should only reconfigure the store and start loading it. 
if you do like this both grid and pagination will work just fine...

i think currently your paginations uses another sotre (another instance or something) but it MUST use the same store as the second grid...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly mean with "does not focus the new context", but are you passing the **start** and **limit** parameters to the second grid in the params array of the jsonStore.load call?

If you just want to focus the grid on certain row, you can use focusRow method of GridView.

Perhaps you could post a code example if this did not help?